# A question about Google Translate

Tags: translation

Yes, I do know this isn't about Chinese language as such, but I'm not sure where else to ask - and I hope people will find it a little bit amusing and forgive my transgression. So, this is my question - can anybody guess why Google Translate always seems to tranlate "仔仔" as "Aberdeen"? It's my grandson's name, and we laugh about it, but I'm curious as well.

Comment: There seems to be an area in HK called Aberdeen which is represented by 仔, maybe it has something to do with that.

Comment: Aberdeen is a place in hong-kong, whose chinese name is 香港仔. And I think 仔仔 is most likely a childhood name, so it's hard to translate that in whatever language.

Comment: Ah, yes, that might well explain it. Interesting. If only it had been an answer, then I could have accepted it and all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is Google makes mistake all the time.

[香港仔](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/14964/) = Aberdeen, Hong Kong (a place's name)

[仔仔](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/15553/)  /zai2*4 zai2*1/ is a colloquial Cantonese term for "boy"

Mistaken '仔仔' as '香港仔', because both are Cantonese term that has the character '仔' in it, is quite a big flaw

Answer (score 0):

Newby answer: Yellow Bridge gave me "young of domestic animals". Yandex gave me "Boy!".It would appear to me that your boy may be very well behaved or domesticated? And it seems Aberdeen is used as a girls name in some countries (google search). You could try asking Google Translate and see what it comes up with. My attempt failed to produce any useful answers, you may need to play around with the question a few times to find the key words that dig up the answer you are looking for.